# How to declare a filled Vector?

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, flash-10

I am using Vectors in Flash 10 for the first time, and I want to create it in the same way I used to do with Arrays, e.g:

```
var urlList : Array = [url1, url2, url3];
```

I have tried various different methods but none seem to work, and I have settled on the following as a solution:

```
var urlList : Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
urlList.push(url1, url2, url3);
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When it doubt, check the AS3 docs. :)

```
var urlList : Vector.<String> = new <String>["str1", "str2", "str3"];
trace(urlList);
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#Vector()

Direct quote of the line I adapted this from in the documentation:

To create a pre-populated Vector instance, use the following syntax instead of using the parameters specified below:

```
 // var v:Vector.<T> = new <T>[E0, ..., En-1 ,];
 // For example: 
 var v:Vector.<int> = new <int>[0,1,2,];
```

Comment: This works correctly, although I'm using FDT and it breaks a bunch of formatting :S Strange - maybe it's time for a new question!

Comment: Interesting syntax.  +1 since you get compile time type checking.

Comment: This didn't work for me, and then I realized it's because I'm using Flash CS4. I was wondering why I wasn't familiar with this syntax. :P

Answer (score 6):

You coerce an array to a Vector:

```
var urlList:Vector.<String> = Vector.<String>([url1, url2, url3]);
```

Comment: If I do this my build fails :(

Comment: @soulBit With what compiler?  This has been supported since vectors were introduced as far as I know.

Comment: Actually soulBit it turns out this does work, so it does at least deserve an upvote. :)

Comment: Actually I wouldn't use this method, because it's proven to be slower than the version provided by @Digital Architect
100 000 pre populated vectors with this method took over 800ms, the other version a little over 500 ms

Comment: Makes sense that it's slower. Why would you perform a type coercion from Array to Vector just to define a vector? The correct answer is the other one, as defined in Adobe's documentation: new <String>[...];